# Text-to-speech: Skip words (especially HTML)

Tags: software-recommendation, audio

I am a frequent user of Apple's built-in Text-to-Speech.

I write a lot of articles in a CMS where the formatting has to be entered as HTML. If I use text-to-speech, it reads the HTML tags.

Is there any way I can get it to skip the tags?

If not are there any free alternatives that will do this. Ideally, the voice should be as good as the Apple Leo voice (as a lot of other programmes sound too robotic).

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Drupal with BUEditor. I know there are WYSIWYG editors available for Drupal, but I find BUEditor produces the cleanest HTML!